# Arduino serial monitor gives question marks and boxes with my output

Tags: c++, arduino, aes, esp32, mbed

I am writing a program to encrypt the given input and send the cipher text over LoRa waves, but I seem to be stuck in this step.
I am using a Heltec LoRa ESP32 and have included the mbedtls library for the AES functions.

```
#include "mbedtls/aes.h"
#include "heltec.h"
#include <SPI.h>

#define BAND    433E6 //setting the LoRa bands to 433 mhz
mbedtls_aes_context aes;

int counter = 0;

unsigned char key[32] = "key"; // 256 bit - AES = 32 bytes for key
unsigned char iv[16];

unsigned char input [128] = "given AES plain text";
unsigned char output[128];

size_t input_len = 40;
size_t output_len = 0;

void setup() {
  Heltec.begin(true /*DisplayEnable Enable*/, true /*Heltec.Heltec.Heltec.LoRa Disable*/, true /*Serial Enable*/, true /*PABOOST Enable*/, BAND /*long BAND*/);
  //setup code to enable LoRa
  
  Serial.begin(115200); //establishing serial communication with esp32 and pc

  mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &aes, key, 256 );
  mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, 48, iv, input, output ); // AES function from mbedtls library,
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  Serial.println((char*)output); //here is the issue

  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print((char*)output);
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  
  counter++;
  delay(5000);

}
```

the output gives a cipher text containing (Im assuming) special characters and when I look at the Arduino serial monitor it shows bunch of reverse question marks and boxes with normal characters.

```
Serial.println((char*)output);
```

Is there a print method that can show these special characters in the Arduino IDE?

Comment: the encrypted output will contain non printable characters. If you want to see what data you have convert it to a hex string

Comment: `Serial.println((char*)output, HEX);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Serial.begin(115200);
```

The value of serial monitory baud should be same as above value.
[image]